# Publish a workbook (twb|twbx) file with Kerberos Impala connection to Tableau

Tags: python, automation, tableau-api

I need to publish a Tableau workbook (both twb and twbx formats) to Tableau Server. The workbook internally connects to Impala using Kerberos mechanism. 
I tried using Tableau Server Client Python (TSC) and also Tabcmd to publish the workbook. But, neither is successful.

I am using below connection format for connecting Impala in .twb workbook file:

```
<
connection authentication='yes' 
authentication-type='1'
class='hadoophive' 
connection-type='Impala' 
dbname='' 
kerberos-host='xyz.com' 
kerberos-realm='abc.com' 
kerberos-service='impala' 
odbc-connect-string-extras='' 
one-time-sql='' 
port='25003' 
schema='someSchema' 
server='someServer' 
sslcert='' 
sslmode='' 
transport-type='1' 
username='someUser'
>
```

Any other API's which can do the this will be great help !!!

Answer (score 1):

Tableau supports Kerberos connections to Impala/Hive ([directions](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-11137)).

If you are successful connecting through Desktop your next step would be to publish directly to server from Desktop.  If that works then you can start looking at API's.

Regardless, the API's don't change any of the connection information upon publishing so you should be successful with any of them.